# How to use an enumeration in a MVC and retain useful text attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a MVC page that will prompt the user to confirm one of 3 operations using a checkbox.  My model looks like:

```
public class InstallViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Upgrade database")]
    [IsTrueAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Please confirm that you wish to perform the upgrade")]
    public bool Upgrade { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Create database")]
    [IsTrueAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Please confirm that you wish to create the database")]
    public bool Create { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delete database")]
    [IsTrueAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Please confirm that you wish to delete the database")]
    public bool Create { get; set; }

    public String Database { get; set; }
    public String DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

And in my view I'm using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Create)` when the ViewBag indicates they are being prompted to use the `Create` operation.  I also have to use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Upgrade)` for the non-create operations.

This seems awfully sloppy, and doesn't lend itself well to new operations (let's say I want to add **Backup**)  Ideally I would like to have an enumeration (Upgrade/Create/Delete) but if I do that, I will lose the benefit of having the DisplayName and ErrorMesssage being customized to the action.  I assume I'm making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your enum like

```
public enum ProductType
{        
    A= 1,        
    B= 2,        
    C= 3
}
```

and in your Model

```
  public class Product
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "ProductType ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "select product type")]
        public ProductType? ProductType { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductTypes
       {
        get
         {
           var types =
           from l in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProductType)).Cast<ProductType>();
           return new SelectList(types, "ID", "Name", this.ProductType);
         }
       }
    }
```

finaly in view

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductType,Model.ProductTypes)
```